# Is implementing fastcgi using C++ feasible?

Tags: c++, fastcgi

Webserver(Apache2/ngnix) + PHP(fastcgi) + MySQL

The above combination is common.

How about using C++ instead of PHP? As there is a C++ driver for MySQL, so database connection won't be a big problem. But how to implement the fastcgi in C++? Is looking at php-fpm a good starting point?

Anyone with similar experience please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/

Comment: Does fastcgipp hava the features like Adaptive process spawning as in php-fpm?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it might be easier to write a C++ extension for PHP that has all your code in it. That way, you can use the PHP fastcgi engine but your entire webapp bypasses PHP (the language and the compiler) entirely.

Answer (score 1):

"[Ablaze](http://tomas.styblo.name/ablaze/) is a FastCGI web application development framework for C++ designed for efficiency, high throughput and lightning response time."

Answer (score 0):

Hi this http://cplusplus-soup.com/2009/12/28/c-instead-of-php-for-the-web/ can be usefull